# Stack Exchange chatroom bridge for a desktop chat interface

Tags: windows, gratis, chat, stack-exchange

I was wondering if anyone had a way to take a [StackExchange chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and create some kind of a bridge to a desktop chat interface like Pidgin. I would like it to meet the following requirements,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10
- Creates a bridge that can be used by [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/), [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/), or another popular desktop chat client